# ERROR: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'

Tags: security, cryptography, aes, encryption-symmetric, aes-gcm

I am trying to implement an image encryption project using AES-GCM algorithm using the concept of master key encryption. The encryption code is working properly by accessing the webcam and clicking a snapshot and encrypting it before saving. But while decrypting the image the code shows the error saying "error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'". How do i resolve this issue?

```
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(derived_key), modes.GCM(iv, tag), backend=default_backend())
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()

    # Decrypt the image
    decrypted_data = decryptor.update(ciphertext) + decryptor.finalize()

    # Convert the decrypted data to an image (assuming it was an image that was encrypted)
    decrypted_image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(decrypted_data, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    # Define the path to the "Decrypted snaps" folder
    decrypted_folder = "Decrypted snaps"

    # Create the "Decrypted snaps" folder if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(decrypted_folder):
        os.makedirs(decrypted_folder)

    # Extract the filename from the input path
    filename = os.path.basename(encrypted_image_filename)

    # Create the path to save the decrypted image in the "Decrypted snaps" folder
    decrypted_image_path = os.path.join(decrypted_folder, filename)
    print(decrypted_image_path)

    # Save the decrypted image
    cv2.imwrite(decrypted_image_path, decrypted_image)
    print(f"Decrypted image saved as '{decrypted_image_path}'")
```

I was using Fernet earlier and i was facing the same issue with it so i switched to GCM, but the issue still pertains.